How to close Chrome window with shell (Windows)
I couldn't find a way to close a specific Chrome tab using the shell, and I need to do this. Alternatively, I need to change the URL of that tab to a second link of my choice. The Chrome browser itself should remain open. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.
I've looked in many places and even asked ChatGPT, but I only found code that closes Chrome, not a solution for closing a specific tab.
